# How to make a python dictionary's output be vertical

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

so the following is the code and what I'm trying to do here is I want the output of the code to be vertical

if I use the following code then the output would be like:  cowsheepchickengoatpig

I want the output to be :

[image]

---

```
animaldictionary={

    "house pets":
    "cat"
    "dog"
    "bird"
    "hamster"
    "snake",

    "farm animals":
    "cow"
    "sheep"
    "chicken"
    "goat"
    "pig"
}

print(animaldictionary[input('enter the category:')])
```

I tried a for loop but it still shows the output horizonally

which is like: cowsheepchickengoatpig

Comment: That dictionary looks malformed - keys are associated with a single value.

Comment: As for your question, print values on separate lines?

Comment: @ndc85430 It is not technically malformed, each value is a single long string

Answer (score 1):

The values are just a single long string. This is probably not what you want.

Use a list:

```py
animaldictionary = {
    "house pets": [
        "cat",
        "dog",
        "bird",
        "hamster",
        "snake"
    ],
    "farm animals": [
        "cow",
        "sheep",
        "chicken",
        "goat",
        "pig"
    ]
}
```

Then to get the output in the way you wanted, you can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with new line:

```py
print('\n'.join(animaldictionary[input('enter the category:')]))
```

If you *really* do want the values to be a single string, you can use multilined strings then you will get the output you want with the code you already have but you will need to be careful with the tabs:

```py
animaldictionary = {
    "house pets":
"""cat
dog
bird"
hamster"
    snake""",
    "farm animals":
    """cow
sheep
chicken
goat
pig"""
}
```

or manually add new lines (probably the worst "solution"):

```py
animaldictionary = {
    "house pets":
    "cat\n"
    "dog\n"
    "bird\n"
    "hamster\n"
    "snake",

    "farm animals":
    "cow\n"
    "sheep\n"
    "chicken\n"
    "goat\n"
    "pig"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got two versions of the answer.

1. Use a function that prints a selected value of the dict vertically
2. A custom class, that inherits all methods from a python dict class {}, and implements a custom behavior.

Both options return an output that you are looking for:

```bash
cow
sheep
chicken
goat
pig
```

Option 1. Using a vertical_print function

```py
animaldictionary = {

    "house pets":
    ["cat",
     "dog",
     "bird",
     "hamster",
     "snake"],

    "farm animals":
    ["cow",
     "sheep",
     "chicken",
     "goat",
     "pig"]
}


def vertical_print(input_dict: dict, category: str):
    """prints a selected dict value vertically

    Args:
        input_dict (dict): dictionary
        category (str): key to select
    """
    print('\n'.join(input_dict.get(category, '')))


vertical_print(animaldictionary, 'farm animals')
```

Option 2. Using a class based on dict class

```py
class VerticalPrintingDict(dict):
    """customized version based on the python dict, 
    will not return an item but a string that prints vertically

    Args:
        dict (class): base class that it inherits from
    """

    def __init__(self, *arg, **kw):
        """initilized using superclass
        """
        super(VerticalPrintingDict, self).__init__(*arg, **kw)

    def __getitem__(self, item) -> str:
        """impementation of a custom method []

        Args:
            item (str): key

        Returns:
            str: string, \n separated
        """
        return '\n'.join(super().__getitem__(item))


custom_dict = VerticalPrintingDict({

    "house pets":
    ["cat",
     "dog",
     "bird",
     "hamster",
     "snake"],

    "farm animals":
    ["cow",
     "sheep",
     "chicken",
     "goat",
     "pig"]
})
print(custom_dict['farm animals'])
```